# Android ExpandableListview Child View Animation?

Tags: android, android-listview, view, android-animation, expandablelistview

I am trying to write a code , to have animation in each child index of the ExpandableListview. But i am trying to have animation in all child index in single click listener. So , i am getting the view from the adapter and wants to do the animation but only animation happens in getChildAt.

**MyCode** :

This is the first index where i want to do the animation.

```
 edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                LayoutInflater infalInflater;
                infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                View convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.package_row, null);

                View view = adapter.getChildView(0, 0, false, convertView, list);

                //View view1 = list.getChildAt(1).findViewById(R.id.swipelist_frontview);

                View view1 = view.findViewById(R.id.swipelist_frontview);

                animate(view1)
                        .translationX(-120)
                        .setDuration(200)
                        .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {

                            }
                        });

        }
    });
```

**ChildView Method :**

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.package_row, null);
    }

    TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.example_row_tv_title);

    txtListChild.setText(childText);
    return convertView;
}
```

In above code , if i am trying to get the view from the adapter and wants to add into animate then , animation is n't happening but from getChildAt , the animation is happening properly.

Please suggest me some solution about my issue.

Comment: why are you passing 0,0 and null,null in `getChildView(0,0,false,null,null)` ? do you know what these parameters mean?

Comment: yes , these are the rootView , and ViewGroup object for the child view

Comment: i updated my post , please check  !!!

Comment: so post `adapter.getChildView` method

Comment: Updated my post , please check !!!

Comment: and now see what happens if convertView == null, since you are passing null convertView... a new R.layout.package_row layout is inflated, and of course it is not attached to your tree list view, so you are starting an animation on some view which is not visible at all

Comment: but i am passing the convertview by inflating the layout , so i am getting the view right

Comment: you are calling getChildView(0,0,false,null,null), right? so convertView == null

Comment: no please check my updated post , adapter.getChildView(0, 0, false, convertView, list);

Comment: its basically the same: this view is again not attached to any parent and it is invisible so your animation has no effect

Comment: so , how can we get the view without using getChildAt

Comment: start your animation from `getChildView` method

Comment: Yes that i can do , but it happens in very weird way , if i click on the button then only animation happens , which items are currently visible but rest all after scroll only. so i want to animation in all items in one click